# Auto Completion Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I've re-created the [Walkthrough: Displaying Statement Completion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  and managed to get it running. However, I was wondering if it was possible to add in custom texts.

[image: Highlighted]

I can't seem to find the place where it shows/calls the highlighted "#adapt-samelevel popup. I would want to make it say a small description instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add custom tests on ICompletionSource.AugmentCompletionSession method  like this:

```
 void ICompletionSource.AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
    {
        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        strList.Add("addition");
        strList.Add("adaptation");
        strList.Add("subtraction");
        strList.Add("test");
        strList.Add("text");
        strList.Add("t~e#@xt");
        strList.Add("@text");
        strList.Add("@aaaaaa");
        strList.Add("~text");
        strList.Add("#adapt-samelevel");
        strList.Add("#abort");
        strList.Add("#adapt");
        strList.Add("#adapt-modified");
        m_compList = new List<Completion>();
        foreach (string str in strList)
           //please add custom texts as you want
            m_compList.Add(new Completion(str, str, "Test", null, null));

        completionSets.Add(new CompletionSet(
            "Tokens",    //the non-localized title of the tab
            "Tokens",    //the display title of the tab
            FindTokenSpanAtPosition(session.GetTriggerPoint(m_textBuffer),
                session),
            m_compList,
            null));
    }
```

It made a constraint in Exec method (class name TestCompletionCommandHandler) with letter and digit. You can modify the constraint. Change the following code

```
if (!typedChar.Equals(char.MinValue) && char.IsLetterOrDigit(typedChar))
            {
                if (m_session == null || m_session.IsDismissed) // If there is no active session, bring up completion
                {
                    this.TriggerCompletion();
                    m_session.Filter();
                }
                else    //the completion session is already active, so just filter
                {
                    m_session.Filter();
                }
                handled = true;
            }
```

As

```
if (!typedChar.Equals(char.MinValue))  //remove the constraint
            {
                if (m_session == null || m_session.IsDismissed) // If there is no active session, bring up completion
                {
                    this.TriggerCompletion();
                    m_session.Filter();
                }
                else    //the completion session is already active, so just filter
                {
                    m_session.Filter();
                }
                handled = true;
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Edit:

You could use Diction instead string, like this:

```
void ICompletionSource.AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> strList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            strList.Add("#adapt-samelevel", "Test1");
            strList.Add("abort", "Test2");
            strList.Add("#adapt-modified", "Test3");
            m_compList = new List<Completion>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in strList)
                m_compList.Add(new Completion(kvp.Key, kvp.Key, kvp.Value, null, null));

            completionSets.Add(new CompletionSet(
                "Tokens",    //the non-localized title of the tab
                "Tokens",    //the display title of the tab
                FindTokenSpanAtPosition(session.GetTriggerPoint(m_textBuffer),
                    session),
                m_compList,
                null));
        }
```

Comment: Hi, that is what I have as of now. But I am trying to change the text that pops up when hovered/scrolled to. As per your example, #adapt-samelevel is highlighted and to the right, it says #adapt-samelevel again. I would want to edit that text into something more helpful. How do I do it?

Comment: As Jason Malinowski said, use Description property

Comment: I don't know how to coincide the strList values to the description. Could you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the code on the reprly, please check it this line //please add custom texts as you want
            m_compList.Add(new Completion(str, str, "Test", null, null));

Comment: Hi, yes but I everything would be "Test" wouldn't it? Like for #adapt-samelevel and #abort and #adapt, will all be labelled test? 

I tried entering multiple 
m_compList.Add(new Completion(str, str, "Test", null, null));
m_compList.Add(new Completion(str, str, "Something", null, null));

but it will not work. Please advice! Thank you.

Comment: please use dictionary instead list<string>, I create a demo as below for your referernce. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDefST_5rkTqSuepI

Answer (score 0):

That's just the [`Description` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.completion.description.aspx) for the completions you're creating and adding.

Comment: I did not add the '#adapt-samelevel' descriptions anywhere. I followed the guide, added in my own completion variables and this came along. The highlighted part.

I would really want to edit that part to give some sort of a hint.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me an example as to how to coincide the "#adapt-samelevel" alongside with a custom description?